# Place a figure next to a text without causing spacing in the text

Tags: spacing, graphics, positioning

I want to place a signature on the right to of the text. However, the picture causes some spacing between the text lines:

[image]

My aim is to reach something like this:

[image]

Or that:

[image]

My Code for this MWE:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[german]{babel}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{graphicx}

 \begin{document}
 \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
 \textbf{Best regards,} \\ Firstname Lastname\\Student B.Sc.
 \hspace{35mm}
 \raisebox{1\dp\strutbox}{\includegraphics[width=10em]{example-image-a}}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution could be a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    \noindent\begin{tabular}{m{4cm}m{5cm}}
        \makecell[l]{\textbf{Best regards,}\\ \\ Firstname Lastname\\Student B.Sc.} & \includegraphics[width=10em]{example-image-a}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]